# Issue in Converting XML file into an object type

Tags: c#, xml, object

I need to convert a xml file into an object type and pass that object to a web service. 
PFB the sample xml.

[image: Sample XML]

While `deserialize` this xml I am getting the below Exception.

```
**`System.InvalidOperationException**`
Additional information: There was an error generating the XML document.
Message: The type `CallingWebserviceTest.Claims` was not expected. Use the XmlInclude or SoapInclude attribute to specify types that are not known statically.
```

Sample code:

```
XmlDocument doc = new XmlDocument();
doc.Load(Path)
StringWriter sw = new StringWriter();
XmlTextWriter tx = new XmlTextWriter(sw);
doc.WriteTo(tx);
Claims c = new Claims();
StringReader strReader = new StringReader(sw.ToString());
XmlSerializer serializer = new XmlSerializer(typeof(Claims));
XmlTextReader xmlReader = new XmlTextReader(strReader);
c = (Claims) serializer.Deserialize(xmlReader);
```

I have even added XmlInclude to handle the exception but then also getting it.

Sample Code for Claims class:

```
[XmlInclude(typeof(CallingWebserviceTest.Claims))]
[Serializable]
//[System.Xml.Serialization.XmlTypeAttribute(AnonymousType = true)]
[System.Xml.Serialization.XmlRootAttribute(Namespace = "", IsNullable = false)]
public class Claims
{
      ---
}

[XmlInclude(typeof(CallingWebserviceTest.ClaimsClaim))]
[Serializable]
//[System.Xml.Serialization.XmlTypeAttribute(AnonymousType = true)]
public  class ClaimsClaim
{
      ---
      ---
}
```

Can anyone please help me resolve this issue?
**Any other suggestion to convert xml to object type are also welcome.**

Comment: do you have some inheritance in your classes? Something like this: `public class ClaimsClaim : Claims`

Comment: Provide a [mcve], and include your XML as *text*, not an image. You can't recreate any issue with what you've provided (see [this fiddle](https://dotnetfiddle.net/Zguf7E)). It seems like the error occurred during *serialising* ('there was an error *generating* the XML'), so it doesn't seem related.

Answer (score 0):

The code flattens

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Xml;
using System.Xml.Linq;


namespace ConsoleApplication32
{
    class Program
    {
        const string FILENAME = @"c:\temp\test.xml";
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            XDocument doc = XDocument.Load(FILENAME);

            Claims claims = new Claims()
            {
                claims = doc.Descendants("Claim").Select(x => new ClaimsClaim()
                {
                    claimID = (string)x.Element("ID"),
                    personID = (string)x.Element("Person").Element("ID"),
                    gender = (string)x.Element("Person").Element("Gender"),
                    encounterType = (int)x.Element("Encounter").Element("Type"),
                    codeTerm = (string)x.Element("Diagnosis").Element("CodeTerm"),
                    codeType = (string)x.Element("Diagnosis").Element("Type"),
                    code = (string)x.Element("Diagnosis").Element("Code"),
                    activityID = (string)x.Element("Activity").Element("ID"),
                    activityCodeTerm = (string)x.Element("Activity").Element("CodeTerm"),
                    start = (DateTime)x.Element("Activity").Element("Start"),
                    activityCode = (int)x.Element("Activity").Element("Code"),
                    quantity = (int)x.Element("Activity").Element("Quantity"),
                    clinician = (string)x.Element("Activity").Element("Clinician"),
                }).ToList()
            };

        }
    }

    public class Claims
    {
        public List<ClaimsClaim> claims { get; set; }
    }


    public  class ClaimsClaim
    {
        public string claimID { get; set; }
        public string personID { get; set; }
        public string gender { get; set; }
        public int encounterType { get; set; }
        public string codeTerm { get; set; }
        public string codeType { get; set; }
        public string code { get; set; }
        public string activityID { get; set; }
        public string activityCodeTerm { get; set; }
        public DateTime start { get; set; }
        public int activityCode { get; set; }
        public int quantity { get; set; }
        public string clinician { get; set; }
    }
}
```

results and uses xml linq

Comment: You need to validate the xml.  You can use VS.  From menu : Project : Add New Item : Xml File.  Paste your xml into view.  The error will show like compiler error in the Error List Window.